# How did spotify made it's section design

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

The overflowing has been hidden with no scrollbar in sight + you could swipe through the list, how did spotify did this?

I'm using tailwindcss if that matters.

[image]

Comment: The simplest similar solution is to hide the horizontal scrollbar with CSS `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

Comment: Use a third party JS plugin to create the swipers, take a look at the free-mode example here https://swiperjs.com/demos#freemode

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the scrollbar si done with `overflow-x-scroll` in tailwindcss.

You can make use of `flex` to make such a design in tailwindCSS. An example is attached here

```html
<script src="http://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="relative flex flex-row items-center space-x-10 overflow-x-scroll bg-gray-500 px-10 py-6 sm:py-12">
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- card2 -->
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- card3 -->
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- card4 -->
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- card5 -->
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- card6 -->
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- card7 -->
  <div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```